# Delphi: Android Keyboard that blocks my TEdit

Tags: delphi, keyboard, listbox, frame, firemonkey

I'm building a Mobile App, I have a frame that contains a lot of TEdit, so when comes to the TEdit that is nearby to the bottom page, when I click on the TEdit, the keyboard will block the TEdit which the user cannot see what is their input value. What can I do to avoid this? These are my attempted code:

FYI, in my frame, I arranged all my item into a ListBox1. And the only TEdit that my mobile keyboard blocking is percentage_edit. What Im trying to do here is, when i clicked on the percentage_edit, the keyboard shall be shown below the percentage_edit TEdit box.

```
procedure TProfileFrame.VirtualKeyboardHidden(Sender: TObject;
  KeyboardVisible: Boolean; const Bounds: TRect);
begin
  ListBox1.Margins.Bottom := 0;
end;

procedure TProfileFrame.VirtualKeyboardShown(Sender: TObject;
  KeyboardVisible: Boolean; const Bounds: TRect);
begin
  ListBox1.Margins.Bottom := Bounds.Height;
  if Assigned(percentage_edit) and percentage_edit.IsFocused then ListBox1.ScrollToItem(ListBoxItem12);

end;
```

Comment: Can you describe what actually happens when you use this code?

Comment: Nothing happens... Because i saw ppl are using this in this scenario, but i dont know where is my mistake

Comment: There isn't a simply answer to this question. The keyboard has a fixed space on the screen that it takes up, so the controls have to move up if they are not to be blocked by the keyboard.

Comment: This demo shows one way to do it. https://github.com/Embarcadero/RADStudio10.4Demos/tree/master/Object%20Pascal/Multi-Device%20Samples/User%20Interface/ScrollableForm